# When do I need al.exe (Assembly Linker)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, localization, .net-assembly, al.exe

I'm reading about localization and there is one subject I don't really get. In the book I'm reading (Developing ASP.Net MVC 4 Web Applications) it says I can use Assembly Linker (al.exe) to create satellite assemblies from .resx files so that the application gains some performance boost instead of reading directly from a file.

Next it gives me an example of how I can create theese satellite assemblies through the `Visual Studio Command Prompt` using `Assembly Linker`. But why should I do that? When I build the application, folders are created in the bin-folder containg a .dll for each language I've created that are .resx-files. Like `en-US/project.resources.dll`.

Have I missed something or aren't these the satellite assemblies refered to when using `al.exe` to create satellite assemblies? What can `al.exe` do that Visual Studio doesn't do when building the application?

Comment: It is a book that goes along with exam 70-486.  You ought to have some idea how satellite assemblies are created if you want to pass the exam.  Otherwise, no, msbuild just does it automatically for you.

Comment: First; "You ought to have some idea how satellite assemblies are created if you want to pass the exam", that's why I ask ;) . Next; So if I understand you correctly, If I create these .dll files through al.exe by doing "al /target:lib /embed:strings.de.resources /culture:de /out:Example.resources.dll" (from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht(v=vs.110).aspx) it's the equliant of what Visual Studio does; nothing more, nothing less?

Comment: No magic happens.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity > select Detailed.  Now you can see the magic.

Comment: Hi Andreas. I thought this question was rather odd myself when doing the  Practise exam, so thanks for asking it. It is nice to understand how VS works under the hood but I cannot see any practise application.